# How do I select multiple args in a command and assign it to a variable? Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want to do so that when I use !pm (user) (some message), my bot will send a private message to the user, although I have no idea how to select everything after the (user) and assign it to a variable, to send it to the user.
My current code looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'pm',
  description: 'Sends a personal message!',
  execute(message, args, client) {
    const pmMessage = args[1];
    client.users.cache.get('464839066781745167').send(pmMessage);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the array index of the `pmMessage`, with the help of that index, you can use the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method which returns the array from specified stating to end index.
Eg:

```
let pmMessage = args.slice(2); //returns array.
```

**Note:** If the end index is not specified, then it considers till the last index of the array.

Now, using the [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method, you can join all the indexes with whatever specified character. Eg:

```
let MessageContent = pmMessage.join(' '); //joined by space.
```

```js
let args = ["UserID","This","represents","the","message","content","to","be","sent"];
console.log(args.slice(1));
console.log(args.slice(1).join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think this should work:

```js
let pm_args = args.slice(1).join(' ')
        
if(args[0]){
    let user = getUserFromMention(args[0])

    if(!user){
        return message.reply('please mention a user.');
    }

    return client.users.cache.get(user.id).send(pm_args);
}

return message.reply('please mention a user.');
```

(This is what I used for mention thingie:)

```js
function getUserFromMention(mention){
    if(!mention) return;

    if(mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')){
        mention = mention.slice(2, -1);

        if(mention.startsWith('!')){
            mention = mention.slice(1);
        }

        return bot.users.cache.get(mention);
    }
};

client.on("message", message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

    const withoutPrefix = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length);
    const split = withoutPrefix.split(/ +/);
    const command = split[0];
    const args = split.slice(1);

    // Code...

});
```